# What is a good way to get a time for the data freshness when the source is log shipped to another server?

Tags: sql-server, backup, log-shipping, disaster-recovery

I'm log shipping from SERVER_A with backups every 10 minutes.
I restore the logs to SERVER_B every 20 minutes.
I pause the restores while I do a DWH load from SERVER_B into SERVER_C

I report out of SERVER_B, and I want to know the time the backup was taken on SERVER_A so that I can show the users how fresh the data is that they are seeing

I can't use the last log backup time from SERVER_A because I'm not sure if that log has been restored to SERVER_B yet.

I can't use the last restore time from SERVER_B because I don't know when the backup was actually taken on SERVER_A.

Any thoughts on a good way to get a time for the data freshness?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to rely on backup history: you can just check the restore history! In addition to having backup history, `msdb` also saves the restore history.

Here's a sample query you might use to find the data freshness, based on most recent backup to be restored.

```
SELECT TOP 5
    RestoredDbName = rh.destination_database_name,
    RestoreDateTime = rh.restore_date,
    SourceServer = bs.server_name,
    SourceDbName = bs.databse_name,
    DataFreshnessDateTime = bs.backup_finish_date
FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory AS rh
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset AS bs ON rh.backup_set_id = bs.backup_set_id
WHERE bs.server_name = 'Log Shipping Source'
AND bs.database_name = 'Log Shipping Source'
ORDER BY bs.backup_finish_date DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer states, restore history is probably the best approach, however, to offer an alternative, another approach I have seen used in the past is to query some high traffic transactional table which has a datestamp for its most recent timestamp value. This doesn't require any permissions outside of the database itself (IE doesn't need msdb permissions)

This works based on a few assumptions

- You have such a table in your database
- It is updated frequently enough to give a meaningful value

for example:

`SELECT TOP 1 TransactionDate FROM Transaction ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC`

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the application add a "canary" table to the DB. It has one column which is a date/time.

Add a step to the backup job, before the backup. This new step updates the canary (or inserts if you want history) with the current time on server A. The value is backed up and log shipped like all other data.